# Amazon Cloudfront is not fast enough even in Hong Kong

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I know that Amazon Cloudfront will increase downloading speed.

However, it said they have server in Hong Kong,

I compared it with my other local webhosting company,

It still seems that the CloudFront still very slow even the images are load many times.

Is that the Amazon CloudFront Server of Hong Kong is still too slow when compare to the local server in the city?

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded a file to Canada server. Got 290KB/s via cloudfront from HK, vs 190KB/s by direct access canadian server. Sounds good to me actually.